# ui-grid grouping line position and grouping not displayed for hidden cells

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to display the grouping aggregation result under the cells data, meaning displaying the cells content and then the aggregation results.

I've tried several tutorial but without result.

Is it also possible to display only the aggregation results without displaying the cells data?

For example in [this UI-Grid Tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping) how we can we display the grouping results after cell data not before and how can we get aggregation results even after hiding for example age details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to display the grouping results after the cells content you need to do that manually, it's not handled by UI-Grid.
you need to define your own function that will replace the aggregation method and then add the results manually to the grid after each section by pushing the results to your uigridoption data. using that method you can also hide the cells that you don't want to display and show only the results of your method.